# Handling events of WPF User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls

I have a user control with several buttons, which need to take different actions depending on the class using it.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement those handlers because when using my user control from the final app I don't have direct access to the buttons to specify which handler handles which events.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another way to do this is to expose the events through events in your UserControl :

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public event RoutedEventHandler Button1Click;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button1Click != null) Button1Click(sender, e);     
    }
}
```

This gives your usercontrol a `Button1Click` event that hooks up to that button within your control.

Comment: Thank you both, those seem like nice solutions. Are there any more alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

I would create a command for each button and delegate for each "handler". Than you can expose delegates to the user (final app) and internally call them on `Execute()` method on the commands. Something like this:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl {
        public ICommand FirstButtonCommand {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public ICommand SecondButtonCommand {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Action OnExecuteFirst {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Action OnExecuteSecond {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public MyControl() {
            FirstButtonCommand = new MyCommand(OnExecuteFirst);
            FirstButtonCommand = new MyCommand(OnExecuteSecond);
        }
    }
```

Of cource, "MyCommand" needs to implement ICommand. You also need to bind your commands to coresponding buttons. Hope this helps.