# How to send data from one User Control to another User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Say I have these two User Controls. How would I pass data entered in the TextBox from `ControlOne`to the TextBox in `ControlTwo` when the Button in `ControlOne` is clicked?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.ControlOne"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Send" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

...
namespace Project
{
    public partial class ControlOne : UserControl
    {

        public ControlOne()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="Project.ControlTwo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: [UI is not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#). Therefore you don't "pass data" between UI elements. You must learn MVVM.

Comment: That is a pretty simple user control.  Why not just skip the UserControl and use two Buttons and two TextBox?

Comment: @HighCore I looked at your link and I am having trouble with the Command class of the MVVM example. What namespace has that class?

@Blam I should have said that `ControlOne` and `ControlTwo` are in different .xaml files. Unless I misunderstood.

Comment: @KrimCard [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

Comment: @HighCore Sorry to ask you this, but everything seems to be going over my head. Would it be too much trouble to ask if you could illustrate how I would use MVVM in the situation I posed above?

Comment: @KrimCard post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to implement it in WPF / MVVM.

Comment: @HighCore My main problem is my original question. However, I am trying to tackle it using what you first linked. Currently, I am trying to get that DelegateCommand to work. I typed up that example from WPFTutorial. Then I tried to use it in a view model. I must admit that I don't really understand the DelegateCommand and don't know how to use it.

[ScreenShot](http://i.imgur.com/6ldgjEr.png)

Edit: Changed the image.

Comment: You don't need `new Action()` and all that stuff. Use lambdas or directly reference the methods.

Comment: @HighCore I see that I am a bit outside of my knowledge. I'll just go read up on MVVM and other things mentioned. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KrimCard, how is controlOne related to control2? I mean where would you use each control? If I understand the structure, maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your two user controls should have no knowledge of each other (unless one contains the other).  That's why you can't "pass data" between them.  The idea behind a user control is that you can drop it anywhere as many times as needed.  If `ControlOne` knew about `ControlTwo`, what would happen if you used them separately?  Or had three `ControlTwo`s in the same place?

The layer which contains both of them should be the one to read a value from one and set it to the other.  If you want it to happen on the button press, you should look into [event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206080/298754) so the parent can know when the control's button is pressed.